# How do it table filter by date using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to filter tables data using date range using only jquery plugins.I have one dropdown box data depends on selected date and date range and values.Howcoz i want to add plugins in my webpage we can do it using plugins b

HTML:

```
<input id="seate" name="" type="text">

<input id="seate2" name="" type="text">

<table>
    <caption>
        Table
    </caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="rody">
        <tr scope="row">
            <td>11</td>
            <td>In-Progress</td>
            <td>11/05/17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr scope="row">
            <td>12</td>
            <td>In-Progress</td>
            <td>02/01/18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr scope="row">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>In-Progress</td>
            <td>11/01/17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr scope="row">
            <td>13</td>
            <td>In-Progress</td>
            <td>11/08/17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr scope="row">
            <td>14</td>
            <td>In-Progress</td>
            <td>11/06/17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr scope="row">
            <td>15</td>
            <td>In-Progress</td>
            <td>11/04/17</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: save the trouble, use plugin. why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: I want to do without plugin

Comment: If you want to do it by hand, I would convert the 15, 30 days etc into time stamps and the same for the dates. That way doing math on it and comparing it with a filter function is very easy.

Comment: Can u edit my jsfiddle?

Comment: 11/04/17 - DD/MM/Year is correct.can you chage to full year like 2018

Comment: Updated jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/4116/

Comment: 11/04/17 - DD/MM/Year is correct????

Comment: Yes Correct  DD/MM/Year

Comment: do u need this format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162801/discussion-between-venka-tesh-user5397700-and-saranchel-n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created the function for table filter

```
function display(startDate,endDate) {
    //alert(startDate)
    startDateArray= startDate.split("/");
    endDateArray= endDate.split("/");

    var startDateTimeStamp = new Date(startDateArray[2],+startDateArray[0],startDateArray[1]).getTime();
    var endDateTimeStamp = new Date(endDateArray[2],+endDateArray[0],endDateArray[1]).getTime();

    $("table tbody.mainBody tr").each(function() {
        var rowDate = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').html();
        rowDateArray= rowDate.split("/");

var rowDateTimeStamp =  new Date(rowDateArray[2],+rowDateArray[0],rowDateArray[1]).getTime() ;
        // alert(startDateTimeStamp<=rowDateTimeStamp)
        // alert(rowDateTimeStamp<=endDateTimeStamp)
        if(startDateTimeStamp<=rowDateTimeStamp && rowDateTimeStamp<=endDateTimeStamp) {
            $(this).css("display","block");
        } else {
            $(this).css("display","none");
        }
    });
}
```

sample function call

```
display("11/08/2017","02/01/2018")
```

Format : `display(startDate,endDate);`

For 30 days display(currentDate-30,currentDate);

Note Pls change the html date format

```
<tr scope="row">
    <td>11</td>
    <td>In-Progress</td>
    <td>11/05/2017</td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: can u do it in jsfiddle?because that is we can easily understand.

Comment: i don't have account. please pass the corresponding startDate and endDate

Answer (score 6):

Here is how you could do it. Note also some minor modifications to the HTML:

```js
$(function(){
    // Initialise the inputs on page load:
    var today = new Date().toJSON().replace(/..(..)-(..)-(..).*/, '$2/$3/$1');
    $("#selectDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy' }).val(today).change(applyFilter);
    $("#selectDate2").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy' }).val(today).change(applyFilter);
    $("#rangeval").change(applyFilter);

    $.fn.date = function () {
        return new Date((this.is(':input') ? this.val() : this.text()).replace(/\/(..)$/, '/20$1'));
    }
    
    function applyFilter() {
        var filterType = $("#rangeval").val(),
            start, end;
        // Set the visibility of the two date fields:
        $("#selectDate").toggle(["Single Date", "Custom Date Range"].indexOf(filterType) > -1);
        $("#selectDate2").toggle(filterType === "Custom Date Range");
        // Depending on the type of filter, set the range of dates (start, end):
        if (filterType === "") {
            // Show all: choose extreme dates
            start = new Date('1000-01-01');
            end = new Date('3000-01-01');
        } else if (!parseInt(filterType)) {
            // Use data entry:
            start = $("#selectDate").date();
            end = filterType === "Custom Date Range" ? $("#selectDate2").date() : start;
        } else {
            // Show last X days:
            start = new Date();
            start.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            start.setDate(start.getDate() - parseInt(filterType));
            end = new Date(); // today
        }
        // For each row: set the visibility depending on the date range
        $(".mainBody tr").each(function () {
            var date = $("td:last-child", this).date();
            $(this).toggle(date >= start && date <= end);
        });
    }
    applyFilter(); // Execute also on page load
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<select class="inputxlg" id="rangeval">
    <option value="">Filter by Date Range</option>
    <option value="15">15 Days</option>
    <option value="30">30 Days</option>
    <option value="90">90 Days</option>
    <option value="365">Last Year</option>
    <option value="Single Date">Single Date</option>
    <option value="Custom Date Range">Custom Date Range</option>
</select>

<input id="selectDate" name="selectDate" type="text">
<input id="selectDate2" name="selectDate" type="text">

<table>
    <caption>
        Table
    </caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="mainBody">
        <tr scope="row">
            <td>11</td>
            <td>In-Progress</td>
            <td>11/05/17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr scope="row">
            <td>12</td>
            <td>In-Progress</td>
            <td>02/01/18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr scope="row">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>In-Progress</td>
            <td>11/01/17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr scope="row">
            <td>13</td>
            <td>In-Progress</td>
            <td>11/08/17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr scope="row">
            <td>14</td>
            <td>In-Progress</td>
            <td>11/06/17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr scope="row">
            <td>15</td>
            <td>In-Progress</td>
            <td>11/04/17</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can i apply this functionality for nested table?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. If you cannot make it to work, then please ask a new question where you pinpoint the specific problem you have in doing so.

Comment: Hi trincot. Please answer this QA:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48182948/apply-filter-option-to-nested-table

Comment: Please answer this Qa. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207149/jquery-toggle-includes-error-in-ie8-9-10

Comment: I am running the snippet that I posted *in* my answer in IE11, and it works fine. What version of IE are you using?

Comment: I am checking in IE 6,8,9,10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163005/discussion-between-saranchel-n-and-trincot).