# Jquery toggle Includes error in IE8,9,10

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery toggle code to get option for if condition. but not working.anyone find this issue.
I am getting this error in IE.Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'

JS:

```
$("#dates").toggle(["Single", "Multi"].includes(filterType));

if (filterType === "") {

} else if (!parseInt(filterType)) { } else{}
```

Comment: Array.includes isn't supported in any IE version. Only in Edge and non-microsoft browsers. Then again, you can polyfill/ repalce it easy by `[].indexOf(filterType) !== -1`.

Comment: can u edit my code?

Comment: This is correct or not?   $("#dates").toggle(["Single", "Multi"].indexOf(filterType)!==-1);

Comment: here not working

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the polyfill to your code.
You can find it in the documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 0):

As written in the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Array.includes() is not supported in any version of IE.
Support for it starts with MS Edge 14.

Luckily enough there's alot of polyfills you can use, or just mimic the behaviour yourself.
Since you only need to know if your array includes a word, you can use `.indexOf()` which will return an index if the element is found, or -1 if not.

So your code becomes something like:

```js
var toggleDates = function( filterType ) {
  var filterIsIncluded = ["Single", "Multi"].indexOf( filterType ) !== -1;
  $("#dates").toggle( filterIsIncluded );
};

$( "#setToSingle" ).click( function() {
  toggleDates( "Single" );
} );

$( "#setToOther" ).click( function() {
  toggleDates( "Other" );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dates">2018-01-11</div>
<button id="setToSingle">Set filterType to "single"</button>
<button id="setToOther">Set filterType to "other"</button>
```

Comment: If i use this one i am getting syntax error:const filterIsIncluded = ["Single", "Multi"].indexOf( filterType ) !== -1;
$("#dates").toggle( filterIsIncluded );

Comment: Changed const to vars and added the runnable snippet.

Comment: pls see my jsfiddle and find that includes and correct it.http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/4138/

Comment: Do you mean http://jsfiddle.net/esepdu1h/ ? For me, the indexOf works exactly as the includes would have. Maybe the issue is elsewhere if this isn't what you are after.

Comment: @Shilly..r u there?

Comment: check in IE8,9,10

Comment: It's jsfiddle itsself that doesn't work for me in IE(11), so I can't test it on IE alas. Have you tried it in an actual web page or a different snippet builder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162988/discussion-between-saranchel-n-and-shilly).